# ReactJS several css files

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router, jsx

Im building a SPA with ReactJS but I have one problem when it comes to styling so I have 3 differente pages(I will add more pages in future) so each file has it own css file I import those files like this

```
*index.jsx
import index form './index.css'*

*page2.jsx
import page3 form './index.css'*

*page3.jsx
import page3 form './index.css'*
```

so when open site in browser I go to **(index)** page it's okay, but when I go to next page **(page2)** then click back and go to **(index)** page styles are changed because I have some classes with same name in two css files and the second css file that has been loaded **(page2.css)** has overrided the **(index.css)** how can I fix that.

Sorry if question isn't much clear,

Thanks !

Comment: You can use css-modules https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: I saw that but it's harder when I have to apply styles dynamically I'm trying to find way without css-modules

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way of distinguishing between the different contexts. It's hard to say without seeing the code, but if there is a parent element in each page to which you can apply an id you could include this in your css selector to target the element you actually want to style in each case.

```
div#inIndex .myStyle {
    /* styles */
}

div#inPage2 .myStyle {
    /* styles */
}

div#inPage3 .myStyle {
    /* styles */
}
```

This would work, but I'm left wondering why you don't just use different class names?

Comment: First of all thanks for answering.
It was my bad to leave styles with same name but now it;s to late to change.

Now I can't understand your comment very well I have each component in seperated files so each component has parent div 
return (<div id="parent">
childs (other components)
</div>);
in that case how can I apply solution that you mention please can u help me little more ?

Comment: Is it too late to edit the class names because you can't access the css files? If that's the case then I don't really see how you can get around this.  The only solutions I can think of would involve editing the css files in order to add some sort of unique selector.

Comment: no no I have access to css files but I'm trying to find and eaiser solution because I need that to be done ASAP for example to apply style only if parent id = 'index' or something like this

Comment: You may be able to do something with ReactDOM to select the node you want to style, then add your style.

`myNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode('#index')

myNode.style.backgroundColour = 'green'
`